# Make a programmatically Created Controller Delegate (Bubble) Events

Tags: ember.js

I have an app with many similar views which I instantiate programmatically to "DRY-up" my app.
The problem is that controllers instantiated programmatically do not delegate actions in the `actions` hash further. This is clear because there is nothing from which the controller can derive the hierarchy. There should be a way, however, to tell a controller which parent controller it has to use for event bubbling. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be initializing controller's on your own. All controller initialization should be handled by Ember itself. Another interesting note, controller's are intended to be singletons in the application. The only exception to this being the itemController when looping over an ArrayController. You can read more about it [in the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/).  Quote from the guides:

> In Ember.js applications, you will always specify your controllers as
>   classes, and the framework is responsible for instantiating them and
>   providing them to your templates.
>
> This makes it super-simple to test your controllers, and ensures that
>   your entire application shares a single instance of each controller.

**Update 1:**

An example of how to do routing for a wizard:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('wizard', function() {
    this.route('step1');
    this.route('step2');
    this.route('step3');
  });
});
```

This way, you can have a separate controller/view/template per step of the wizard. If you have logic around how much of each step should be completed prior to transitioning to the next one, you can handle that in the individual routes.

**Update 2:**

In the event that the number of steps aren't predetermined, but are based on the data being fed to the app, you can make a WizardController that is an ArrayController where each item in the array is a step in the wizard. Then, use the `lookupItemController` hook on the ArrayController, kind of like this:

```
App.WizardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {controllerName: 'step1', templateName: 'step1'},
      {controllerName: 'step2', templateName: 'step2'},
      {controllerName: 'step3', templateName: 'step3'}
    ];
  }
});


App.WizardController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  lookupItemController: function(modelObject) {
    return modelObject.controllerName;
  }
});

{{#each step in controller}}
  {{view Ember.View templateName=step.templateName}}
{{/each}}
```

As another, probably better, alternative, you can override the renderTemplate hook in the route where you're pulling down the model for the next step in the wizard and pass in the appropriate templateName and controller in the render call, kind of like you [see here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate).

Point being, I think it should be possible to do this without having to instantiate controllers yourself.

Comment: Theoretically and from an architectural point of view you are right but I think my application is complex enough that I can think of no better way.The alternative would be massive code duplication. I use this for a wizard component where each step in the wizard is different and thus needs a different controller/ view. The component itself is used to realize many different wizards which have varying steps.

Comment: I can think of a few different ways of handling this that stay in the realm of ember's conventions. I built a Wizard in an Ember app I worked on via ember's routes and it's a good fit, assuming the steps in the wizard are somewhat deterministic. I can't put code samples in my comment so I'll update my answer to include a code sample.

Comment: That definitly works but my wizard component does not require each step to be defined. I have a route with dynamic segment and the view/ controller of a step is dynamically determined by naming conventions.
As always there are pros and cons of either solution that don't want to discuss further.

Comment: Updating comment again for that case.

Comment: Thanks good points. Regarding your second update: Is it possible to have a ArrayController for each steps. For example to show a list of products to choice from in one step? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148430/accordion-wizard-with-multiple-steps-in-ember)

Comment: Yup, each of the step controllers can be whatever specific type of controller you wish. It just depends on how they are defined. I posted an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I set the model of the ArrayController then? For example the list of products in step2?

Comment: I would probably set the model inside the `setupController` hook for the Wizard route.

Comment: lookupItemController doesnt seem to work together with iterating over ArrayControllers. When i use ObjectControllers it works but not with ArrayControllers. With array controllers a #each over the steps does not work

Comment: Could you put together a jsbin?